# Single events channel with multiple consumer groups (with competing members)

Tags: message-queue, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a scenario where I want to publish actions in a single channel and want multiple groups of consumers compete for actions they are specialized to process.

E.g. 2 types of actions with an attribute indicating their type:

1. Complex action
2. Simple action

Then, I need 2 groups of consumers (that I can scale in/out based on the load) to process 2 types of actions.

The solution should be as simple/cheap as possible.

Options I considered so far: Azure Service Bus, RabbitMQ, Kafka.

Azure SB approach I came up with seems a bit complex:
Single topic with subscribers sending filtered actions to 2 separate queues and consumers processing actions.

Is there a simpler/cheaper ootb approach in azure?

Suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm no answers yet.  Here are a few questions that might provide more focus to your broad question.  Are you asking whether Azure has an existing solution?  Or whether some other solution could be deployed in Azure?  If you're only interested in Java solutions, say so specifically.  Also, would be helpful to hear precisely what seems "a bit complex" of about the solution you mentioned.  Good luck.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.